# A script to change file names

Tags: awk, sed, echo

I am new to awk and shell based programming. I have a bunch of files name `file_0001.dat`, `file_0002.dat......file_1000.dat`. I want to change the file names such as the number after file_ will be a multiple of 4 in comparison to previous file name. SO i want to change

```
file_0001.dat to file_0004.dat
file_0002.dat to file_0008.dat
```

and so on.

Can anyone suggest a simple script to do it. I have tried the following but without any success.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(echo $1 sed -e 's:file_::g' -e 's:.dat::g')
b=$(echo "${a}*4" | bc)
shuf file_${a}.dat > file_${b}.dat
```

Comment: I cna help you with a java or php script for this. You will have to first scan folder and keep all file names, then map them to the new names, then start from the highest and go to lowest. As if u go from lowest - there will be conflicts. example u cant rename 001 to 004 if there is a 004 from before.

Comment: @tgkprog - Looks like he wants to use awk/sed/bash (which are better tools for this task).

Comment: You should choose a correct answer, why? See the [faq]

Answer (score 2):

This script will do that trick for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls -r *.dat`; do
    a=`echo $i | sed 's/file_//g' | sed 's/\.dat//g'`
    almost_b=`bc -l <<< "$a*4"`
    b=`printf "%04d" $almost_b`
    rename "s/$a/$b/g" $i
done
```

Files before:

> file_0001.dat  file_0002.dat

Files after first execution:

> file_0004.dat  file_0008.dat

Files after second execution:

> file_0016.dat  file_0032.dat

Comment: start from the highest and go to lowest. As if u go from lowest - there will be conflicts. example u cant rename 001 to 004 if there is a 004 from before ...what if it at first you have file_0001.dat, file_0001.dat, ... file_0004.dat... ?

Comment: Thanks tgkprog - I have changed the code to prevent that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure bash way of doing it (without bc, rename or sed).

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(ls -r *.dat); do
   prefix="${i%%_*}_"
   oldnum="${i//[^0-9]/}"
   newnum="$(printf "%04d" $(( 10#$oldnum * 4 )))"
   mv "$i" "${prefix}${newnum}.dat"
done
```

To test it you can do

```
mkdir tmp && cd $_
touch file_{0001..1000}.dat
(paste code into convert.sh)
chmod +x convert.sh
./convert.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bash/sed/find:

```
files=$(find -name 'file_*.dat' | sort -r)
for file in $files; do
    n=$(sed 's/[^_]*_0*\([^.]*\).*/\1/' <<< "$file")
    let n*=4
    nfile=$(printf "file_%04d.dat" "$n")
    mv "$file" "$nfile"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`ls -r1 | awk -F '[_.]' '{printf "%s %s_%04d.%s\n", $0, $1, 4*$2, $3}' | xargs -n2 mv`

1. `ls -r1` list file in reverse order to avoid conflict
2. the second part will generate new filename. For example: `file_0002.dat` will become `file_0002.dat file_0008.dat`
3. `xargs -n2` will pass two arguments every time to `mv`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
paste <(seq -f'mv file_%04g.dat' 1000) <(seq -f'file_%04g.dat' 4 4 4000) | 
sort -r | 
sh
```

Answer (score -1):

This can help:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat /path/to/requestedfiles |grep -o '[0-9]*'`; do
   count=`bc -l <<< "$i*4"`
   echo $count
done
```